# Unable to update the default certificate on application load balancer using aws cli

Tags: aws-cli, lets-encrypt, aws-application-load-balancer

I have generated a certificate for a domain using letsencrypt and imported it in acm using aws cli. However when I try to update the default certificate on the loadbalancer, I get below error. I can see that the certificate has been imported into the acm. Please let me know if I am missing anything. Also, I did verify that the loadbalancer is present in the right region. I am not sure why I am getting below error.

`Error`:
An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the SetLoadBalancerListenerSSLCertificate operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'loadbalancer-name'

Here are my steps -

1. Generate certificate for my domain 'abc..co.
   certbot certonly --dns-route53 --dns-route53-propagation-seconds 60 -d abc.domain.co --agree-tos --no-bootstrap --preferred-challenges dns-01
2. Import certificate into ACM -
   aws acm import-certificate --certificate fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.domain.co/cert.pem --certificate-chain fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.domain.co/chain.pem --private-key fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.domain.co/privkey.pem
3. Update the ssl listener on the loadbalancer -

   aws elb set-load-balancer-listener-ssl-certificate --load-balancer-name loadbalancer --load-balancer-port 443 --ssl-certificate-id arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:8443XXXXXXX:certificate/xxxxx-ab3b-4036-b65e-f6cee35735a8 --region us-west-1

Comment: Have you tried to use quotation marks in parameter value?
Like ``aws elb set-load-balancer-listener-ssl-certificate --load-balancer-name 'loadbalancer'`` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by updating the listener using the command below

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener \
--listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:844333597536:listener/app/loadbalancer/xxxx981b/xxxxxx94e7 \
--certificates CertificateArn=arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:xxxxxxxx7536:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxx35a8 \
--region us-west-1
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-certificates.html#replace-default-certificate